# What is wrong with my linked list implementation?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, linked-list

Well, first of all ,
I have to confess, I've really didn't implemented linked-list, Hmm, for truth, I did not use C recently.

So I'm sure that a really stupid simple bug.

Well (don't know why - but I just like this word) , 
I tried to refresh a bit my mind, then I decided to implement some simple linked list.

```
void addToLast(linkedList* head, int data) {
    linkedList* ptr = head; // points to ptr
    while(ptr) /* p ins't null */ ptr = ptr->next;
    // ptr now is null
    ptr = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList)); // we have new node
    if(ptr == NULL) printf("DAFUQ Null\n");
    ptr->num = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;
//  return!
    return;
}
```

Well, for some strange reason in every iteration ptr's value is NULL.

It's seems like whenever I call `addToLast` function, ptr stays NULL.

I really don't know why - either I really tired, or I just have a stupid problem.

Well, as I said - I can't understand why ptr stays NULL,

I allocate a new node -

```
ptr = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList)); // we have new node
```

So why ptr doesn't saves its value??

The main & print functions:

```
void printList(linkedList* list) {
linkedList* p;
putchar('[');
for(p = list;p;) {
    printf("%d, ",p->num);
    p = p->next;
}
putchar(']');
```

}

```
int main() {
    // create list
    linkedList *root = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
    root->next = NULL;
    addToLast(root,0);
    addToLast(root,5);
    printList(root);
    system("pause");
    return 0; // blet :o
}
```

Comment: apart from the memory leak, not much at all. you walk *next pointers until you reach a null, create a new node, and assign it....um.. nowhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that the last node in the list is still pointing to `NULL`. You have to save the last node:

```
void addToLast(linkedList* head, int data) {
    linkedList* ptr = head, *last; // points to ptr
    while(ptr) /* p ins't null */ {
        last = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    // ptr now is null
    ptr = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList)); // we have new node
    if(ptr == NULL) printf("DAFUQ Null\n");
    ptr->num = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    last->next = ptr;
//  return!
    return;
}
```

or like that

```
void addToLast(linkedList* head, int data) {
    linkedList* ptr = head;
    while(ptr->next) ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList)); // we have new node
    if(ptr == NULL) printf("DAFUQ Null\n");
    ptr->next->num = data;
    ptr->next->next = NULL;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

in your function you never assign the next of you previous last element, and you stop your loop when ptr point to null you have to stop before that

```
void addToLast(linkedList* head, int data) {
    linkedList* ptr = head; // points to ptr
    linkedList* last= null; // new element

    last = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList)); // we have new node
    if(last == NULL) 
        printf("DAFUQ Null\n");

    last ->num = data;
    last ->next = NULL;

    while(ptr->next!=null) 
        ptr = ptr->next;

    ptr->next=last;
}
```

Comment: Well it depends what kind of behavior you wanna have, if your head pointer could be null you have to make some modification to the function

Comment: that would be the impl i posted at the end of all this. he'll figure that out soon enough, i imagine.

Answer (score 0):

```
void addToLast(linkedList **head , int data){
linkedList *temp, *r;
temp = *head;

if(*head == NULL)//list is empty create first node
{
temp = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
temp->num = data;
temp->next = NULL;
*head = temp;
}
else
{

//go to last node    
while(temp->next!=NULL)
temp = temp->next;

//add node at end
r = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
r->num = data;
r->next = NULL;
temp->link = r;
}
}
```

i just passed the pointer head as pointer to pointer that is `linkdList **head` instead of `linkedList *head`